# Syncing bash profile between computers

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, .bash-profile

I have tons of stuff in my .bash_profile. The problem is, I use ~3 computers very frequently, and I'm tired of having to copy paste my prefs everywhere. Two of them run Ubuntu 10.10, and one runs OSX. I was wondering if there was a way to use Dropbox, to share a single prefs file. Like, when bash starts, tell it to check `~/Dropbox/Bash/.bash_profile` ?

Although, could I also tell emacs to look in `~/Dropbox/Emacs/.emacs` somehow?

Comment: Clever question!

Comment: I can't seem to comment on the (great) selected answer.  

I don't know if this is something specific to osx/mac but I needed to make a couple of changes for it to work

 DROPBOX_PROFILE='~/Dropbox/Bash/.bash_profile'
 if [ -f $DROPBOX_PROFILE ]; then
     . $DROPBOX_PROFILE
 fi
 
Should be

 DROPBOX_PROFILE="$HOME/Dropbox/Bash/.bash_profile"
 if [ -f $DROPBOX_PROFILE ]; then
     . $DROPBOX_PROFILE
 fi

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just to make it clearer: @Jason's tweaks are to replace the single-quotes with double-quotes and to replace '~' with '$HOME' in the definition of DROPBOX_PROFILE

Answer (score 18, accepted):

~/.bash_profile

```
DROPBOX_PROFILE='~/Dropbox/Bash/.bash_profile'
if [ -f $DROPBOX_PROFILE ]; then
    source $DROPBOX_PROFILE
fi
```

~/.emacs

```
(load "~/Dropbox/Emacs/.emacs")
```

Comment: I personally feel that `source` is more readable (and googlable) than the dot operator, but it is your answer and so I will not edit it. Other than that, +1 for a good answer.

Comment: @Hello71 Can you elaborate on `source` a bit. I'm intrigued. Thanks!

Comment: @Hello71 Ah, I think I know what you mean now. And I completely agree. using `.` is much more cryptic than using `source`.

Comment: If you have a space in your path, like when you have a business Dropbox and want to use your personal one, e.g. `Dropbox (Personal)`, you'll need to use double quotes when referencing the variable, like `"$DROPBOX_PROFILE"`.

Answer (score 6):

How about this, which avoids having special config files that source the Dropbox versions?

```
$ ln -s ~/Dropbox/Bash/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile
$ ln -s ~/Dropbox/Emacs/.emacs ~/.emacs
```

Answer (score 5):

In your regular .bash_profile, just call ~/Dropbox/Bash/.bash_profile.

```
#.bash_profile
. ~/Dropbox/Bash/.bash_profile # the '.' command runs a file.
```

Actually, you probably want to call the shared file something else, or at least not make it a hidden file.

Answer (score 3):

I think this would get what you want, just check to see if the file exists, if so, source it.

in `$HOME/.bash_profile`

```
[ -f $HOME/Dropbox/Bash/.bash_profile ] && source $HOME/Dropbox/Bash/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

Also check out "homeboy" for general development machine sync'ing and updating: https://github.com/preston/homeboy

Answer (score 0):

> comment to: https://superuser.com/a/224204/401026 (Answer of Andrejs Cainikovs)

my changes for macOS 10.12.6 Sierra, iTerm2 Build 3.2.0, Terminal Version 2.7.3 (388.1.1):
- replaced tilde
- replace single quotes by double quotes

```
DROPBOX_PROFILE="/Users/xxx/Dropbox/Bash/.bash_profile"
if [ -f $DROPBOX_PROFILE ]; then
    . $DROPBOX_PROFILE
fi
```

sorry: I couldn't write comments, so I have to add another answer